# Hibernate duplicate entry with OneToMany relation

Tags: java, database, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

For example I have a user entity in hibernate with these 2 fields:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JsonIgnore
    private Set<User> addedUsers;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JsonIgnore
    private Set<User> wantToAdd;
}
```

`addedUsers` is for 2 people who agrees to match with each other, while `wantToAdd` is for an user who sends a friend request to another user but didn't receive a response yet.
Here's a series of queries I used: (assume there are 3 users a,b,c)

```
a add b -> good  
a add c -> good   
b add c -> failed
```

Now it gives
`"java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '1' for key 'UK_4l1fmdm138stci88r2ht2ggff'"` error.
[Table in MySQL workbench](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5b35F.png)
It seems like want_to_match_id doesn't allow duplicate. How to fix this problem?

I also think it's bad for user reference to itself but I don't know how I could do otherwise.

Comment: So why you use Entity class as column in same Entity class ? -- It's not work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the column `want_to_match_id` to match the user ids to the userids that are matched with that person. But you have added a unique key constraint on the column `want_to_match_id` which is causing the issue.When you add the unique key constraint to this column it means that you cannot match the same user id to multiple persons. Suppose i have  a userid 1 for person A and have to match it for user id 2 and 3 of Person B and Person C . But i also want to match Person B with Person C , so the table entries will end up looking like (as per the details in question ):

```
user_id | want_to_match_id
1           2
1           3
2           3
```

But  you have a unique key constraint on the column which won't allow this entry causing the issue. You should look at redesigning your table structure to better reflect your requirements.

Comment: So should I still keep a list of User in my User class? Or should I redesign it and make another class called Friend, and add a list of Friend  instead of User?